# ORA-00904 - Invalid Identifier in Dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to get to the bottom of `ORA-00904 - Invalid Identifier` error that I'm getting in my stored procedure.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CDG4_HIER_GET_SUBTREE(pDimensionId IN VARCHAR2, pPeriodId IN NUMBER, pNodeId IN NUMBER, pMode IN CHAR, rCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS

v_table_name VARCHAR2(30);
v_function_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'CDG4_HIER_MGR_HAS_CHILDREN'; -- some function defined in the same package
InvalidMode EXCEPTION;
---
v_sql VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN

-- Get dynamic table name
v_sql := 'SELECT UPPER(TABLE_ID)'
      ||'FROM CDG4_CFG_MAP_GER '
      ||'WHERE UPPER(DIMENSION_ID) = UPPER(''' || pDimensionId || ''') ';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_table_name;

IF pMode = 'F' THEN

    -- Do something

ELSIF pMode = 'S' THEN

    v_sql := 'SELECT A.PERIODO_K, '
           ||'      A.FIGLIO_K, '
           ||'      A.PADRE_K, '
           ||'      A.F_LAYOUT, '
           ||'      A.F_VISUALIZZA, '
           ||'      DECODE(A.PADRE_K, NULL, NULL, B2.CODICE) AS CODICE_PADRE, '
           ||'      A.F_ORDINE, '
           ||'      DECODE(A.GEN1, ''2'', ''I'', A.GEN1) AS GEN1, '
           ||'      A.GEN2, '
           ||'      A.GEN3, '
           ||'      ''[''|| B1.CODICE || ''] - '' || B1.DESCR AS DESCR, '
           ||'      ''[''|| B1.CODICE || ''] - '' || B1.DESCR AS DESCRIZIONE, '
           ||'      ' || v_function_name || '(''' || pDimensionId || ''', ' || pPeriodId || ', A.FIGLIO_K) AS HAS_CHILDREN '
           ||'FROM DM_GERARCHIE A, DIM_BO_CANALE_PRIMARIA B1, DIM_BO_CANALE_PRIMARIA B2 '
           ||'WHERE A.FIGLIO_K = B1.CODICE_K '
           ||'AND A.PADRE_K = B2.CODICE_K '
           ||'AND UPPER(A.DIMENSION_ID) = UPPER(''' || pDimensionId || ''') ' 
           ||'AND UPPER(B1.DIMENSION_ID) = UPPER(''' || pDimensionId || ''') ' 
           ||'AND UPPER(B2.DIMENSION_ID) = UPPER(''' || pDimensionId || ''') '
           ||'AND A.PERIODO_K = ' || pPeriodId
           ||' AND A.FIGLIO_K = ' || pNodeId;

ELSE 

    RAISE InvalidMode;

END IF;

OPEN rCursor FOR v_sql;

EXCEPTION
WHEN InvalidMode THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, 'Invalid selection mode.');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004, 'Generic error - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

END;
```

Oracle seems not to be able to identify the function `v_function_name` (it is in the same package) as it keeps returning `ORA-00904` while opening the cursor `rCursor`.

Any hint to a plausible clause of this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you probably have a typo somewhere, but nobody here is going to be able to decipher that string.  Print out the value of v_str and try running that from sqlplus or other sql client.  Also you should not be putting query parameters in the string as literals.  look at the "USING" clause. That will eliminate a lot of the double/triple quoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Oracle seems not to be able to identify the function `v_function_name` (it is in the same package

Dynamic SQL is executed as SQL but outside of the scope of the package. That means we need to build a valid SQL statement. If you were running a similar static SELECT statement you would have written `package_name.v_function_name` because your SQL would execute outside the package. And that's what you need to do here.

---

Although now I've looked more closely at your code and I don't understand why you are using Dynamic SQL at all. You could execute your statements as static SQL with bind variables and parameters.

```
OPEN rCursor FOR 
    SELECT A.PERIODO_K, 
           A.FIGLIO_K, 
           A.PADRE_K, 
           A.F_LAYOUT, 
           A.F_VISUALIZZA, 
           DECODE(A.PADRE_K, NULL, NULL, B2.CODICE) AS CODICE_PADRE, 
           A.F_ORDINE, 
           DECODE(A.GEN1, ''2'', ''I'', A.GEN1) AS GEN1, 
           A.GEN2, 
           A.GEN3, 
           '[' || B1.CODICE || '] - ' ||  B1.DESCR AS DESCR, 
           '[' || B1.CODICE || '] - ' || B1.DESCR AS DESCRIZIONE, 
            package_name.v_function_name (pDimensionId ,pPeriodId , A.FIGLIO_K) AS HAS_CHILDREN 
      FROM DM_GERARCHIE A, DIM_BO_CANALE_PRIMARIA B1, DIM_BO_CANALE_PRIMARIA B2 
      WHERE A.FIGLIO_K = B1.CODICE_K 
      AND A.PADRE_K = B2.CODICE_K 
      AND UPPER(A.DIMENSION_ID) = UPPER( pDimensionId )  
      AND UPPER(B1.DIMENSION_ID) =  UPPER( pDimensionId )  
      AND UPPER(B2.DIMENSION_ID) = UPPER( pDimensionId )  
      AND A.PERIODO_K = pPeriodId
      AND A.FIGLIO_K = pNodeId;
```